# Three.js How to calculate, how far one object collided into another after rotation?

Tags: javascript, three.js, rotation

I have a box, inside which I place a figure. I want user to be able to move, scale and rotate this figure, but, it should never get outside of the box. I had no problem implementing such restrict on movement and scaling, but I have no idea how to calculate this distance:

[image: Seeked distance]

and without knowing it I am not able to move my figure inside the box after rotation.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

P.S. If I forgot to mention anything, that you considered as important, please tell me about it and I will be happy to provide any required information.

Comment: Generally speaking, the easiest way it to ensure that the bounding box of the object does not extend beyond the bounds of the container bounding box. Keep in mind that re-computing the bounding box can be an expensive operation, because it needs to check all of the vertices in the model.

Comment: Firstly, thank very much for your reply. Secondly, I do use bounding box to prevent figure from getting outside of the box while moving (changing position property), but I do not have clear understanding how to do the same for rotation.

Once I get `boundingBox`es objects my box and figure I can calculate borders, which figure shouldn't cross and so prevent it from leaving the box, values from the `boundingBox`, do not change after rotation, actually as far as I know nothing, accept for **rotation** and **quaternion** changes after rotation.

Comment: I believe some extra math is required here, to take rotation angle into account, but unfortunately I am not familiar enough with 3D to do it.

I also tried to check `intersectsBox` for `boundingBox`es but, I always get true. I suppose it is because figure is placed inside the box, and the box itself is not hollow

Comment: Try this: Use your bounding box to calculate each of the 8 corners (as `Vector3`s). Apply the object's world transform to each of the corner vectors (`corner1Vec.applyMatrix4(mesh.matrixWorld);`) and check if they are outside your box. It may be less precise than you want, but it's a starting point.

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much, I am gonna try this